# SQL statement in creating view

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, view

My goal is to create a view with three columns which are `id, revenue` (calculated) and `year`. I am able to get `id` and `revenue`. However, my date column is in `varchar` format.

I have no idea how to do this. Below is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    id,
    SUM(fborders.quantity * fbmenu.fbMenuUnitPrice) as revenue
FROM
    fb.fborders
        INNER JOIN
    fb.fbmenu ON fborders.fbMenuId = fbmenu.fbMenuId
WHERE
    date = (SELECT 
            YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y'))
        from
            fb.fborders
        WHERE
            YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y')) = '2011'
                OR YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y')) = '2012'
                OR YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y')) = '2013')
GROUP BY id
```

My output:

```
id | revenue | year 
_______________________
R1 | 100     | 2011
R1 | 999     | 2012
R1 | 832     | 2013
R2 | 323     | 2011
R2 | 318     | 2012
R2 | 111     | 2013
R3 | 432     | 2011
R3 | 342     | 2012
R3 | 873     | 2013
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you really want to do is group by on the year:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    id,
    SUM(fborders.quantity * fbmenu.fbMenuUnitPrice) as revenue,
    YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y')) as year
FROM
    fb.fborders
        INNER JOIN
    fb.fbmenu ON fborders.fbMenuId = fbmenu.fbMenuId
GROUP BY
    id,
    YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y'))
```